# Is wifi connection between iphone and any other electronic device possible

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to connect an iPhone with any electronic devices through Wi-Fi, and receive signals from it. I'm currently looking into a sample app with UDPEcho, but it is for Mac.

Comment: Yes, iPhones can communicate at least with WLAN routers, which are electronic devices as well ;)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. From your question it's not clear what you are asking, if this isn't answer to it.

Comment: With any electronic device - definitely not, there must be support for the same protocols on both sides (my microwave oven is also an electronic device, it even operates on similar wavelengths ;)). Did you mean an ad-hoc WiFi network? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network

Comment: You can create an adhoc WiFi connection to other Wifi devices supporting adhoc connection.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable suggestions.                             I want to configure a device by passing him some values. The device is already connected to the wifi in adhoc mode. So how can I pass the data to configure device and get an acknowledgment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 20$ a month for 2GB Verizon offers creating a hotspot. At&t does not